# Getting null response using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

```
{
  "vUserList": [
    {
      "firstName": "Kate",
      "lastName": "Bell",
      "email": "katebell@mac.com"
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Higgins",
      "firstName": "Daniel",
      "email": "dhiggins@mac.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "JohnAppleseed@mac.com",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Appleseed"
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Haro",
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "email": "annaharo@mac.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "hankzakroff@mac.com",
      "firstName": "Hank",
      "lastName": "Zakroff"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the request parameters which I need to send to the server.

```
func getContactsParameters() -> [String : Any] {
        return [Keys.vUserList : arrContacts]
    }

var headers = [
                Keys.XAPIKEY: "5dik8fo5yecc25bfcc562724dd674bde5fh5ju8y"
            ]

Alamofire.request("urlString", method: .post, parameters: getContactsParameters(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
}
```

getContactsParameters() console log is as below,
[image]
In response, I am getting Null with the Success code.

I talked with backend people, they are saying, if I don't receive this key "vUserList" then you may get null response. But, I double-checked the spelling and everything.
Another scenario is that, they are saying if we don't get request in proper json then you may get null response.

I tried many different solutions, none of them are working. :(

Any help is appreciated!

Here I am attaching, postman screenshot. In postman it is working fine.
[image]

Comment: can you show what your `getContactsParameters()` returns

Comment: also you can verify the method used for api...Is it `.get` or `.post`?

Comment: First try in postman, and see the response code you are getting.

Comment: I think you need to pass the JSON string of your contact array. Can you please cross verify with backend people for the required format?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com Updated my answer with getContactsParameters() returns

Comment: @Mahendra I verfied, it is post only. In postman it is working fine.

Comment: @Mahendra I added postman screenshot as well

Comment: @HardikS They are saying it should be json... Now I am not sure whether it is string or object.

Comment: @iGatiShah try adding `"Content-Type":"application/json"`
in your headers.

Comment: @iGatiShah According to the postman screenshot, you may need to send the only array of emails? Can you please confirm?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com Tried, not working.

Comment: @HardikS No that is not the case. I udpated postman screenshot in my question. Please check.

Comment: Can you verify you are passing in header correct format key and value?

Comment: @iGatiShah now try `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and in your Alamofire.request , change `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.default` . Actually try both . JsonEncoding as well as URLEncoding.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com Getting this response for above scenarios you asked to try, SUCCESS: { DATA = "<null>"; MESSAGE = ""; STATUS = 1; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the JSON string object of your contact array into your API params.

```
let arrOfUserList : [[String : AnyObject]] = [
            ["firstName":"Kate" as AnyObject,"lastName":"Bell" as AnyObject,"email":"katebell@mac.com" as AnyObject],
            ["firstName":"Daniel" as AnyObject,"lastName":"Higgins" as AnyObject,"email":"dhiggins@mac.com" as AnyObject]
        ]

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrOfUserList, options: [])
    let jsonString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

     if jsonString != nil {

        let paramsContact = [Keys.vUserList : jsonString]

            //Do your API calling code here
     }
 } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

After Check your Postman

Please Add Header in your request

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]
```

If it doesn't work then

`URLEncoding()` or `URLEncoding.httpBody` or `URLEncoding.default`  at the place of `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: I tried above one, and getting this response. SUCCESS: {
    DATA = "<null>";
    MESSAGE = "";
    STATUS = 1;
}

Comment: @iGatiShah Did you added  URLEncoding.httpBody as well ?. Because I don't think you need to do Decode manually like suggested in accepted answer

Comment: Yes,  I added that as well! But, it was not working!